# laravel cashier not updating subscription name

Tags: laravel, stripe-payments, checkout, laravel-cashier

I am using redirectToBillingPortal() in which the user can change the subscription plan, that works fine as it does change stripe_price but it does not change the name assigned, looking at the forums the name is not supposed to update; but then how are you supposed to distinguish between subscription tiers with e.g. subscribed('tier2') if the user changed their plan?

I can imagine a few ways, but would like to consider what the proper way to do this might be:

- intercept "customer.subscription.updated" event and update subscriptions name of that user (interfering with a managed cashier table feels odd)
- write a custom wrapper that checks stripe_price and maps that to the plan (lose access to subscribed() method)

Both seem like it's definitely the wrong way of achieving this, but how else would I do this and retain subscribed('name') functionality to check pricing tiers?

I would also like to keep the external portal and avoid having to reinvent the subscription management stripe offers if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume the two prices you're working with are part of the same Product? I think the only ways to achieve what you've described are to have a 1:1 relationship between Prices and Products, or inspect the subscription's Price and have a mapping on your end between Price ID and tier name.

Comment: @LauraT thanks, it's two separate products; regarding the mapping, is there at least a better way than running through: `subscriptions()->where('stripe_status','active')`?

Comment: what's the problem you're trying to solve by retrieving active subscriptions?

Comment: to get the stripe_price column(s) and map that to billing tier(s) for the current user

Answer (score 0):

To check the plan of a user just use `subscribedToProduct` method and use the product id of Stripe (eg 'prod_xxxxxxxxxxxx')